# HDD temperature difference between linux and windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-11, temperature, pop-os

On Windows 11 and Pop OS dual boot laptop (both operating systems installed on ssd and linux /home and data shared between both OS on Seagate ST1000LM048 HDD) HDD operates within 35-38 degree celcius when using windows.

In power options - setting to turn off hdd are set to default values of 20 minutes.

While running pop os HDD temperature rises by 10-15 degree celcius and operates within 45-50 degree celcius.

I tried setting APM values using `hdparm` command to 127 (permitting spindown after 127 * 5 seconds i.e. approx 10 minutes), 128 and 240 ( but did not observe much difference in temperature.

Also using powertop set `link_power_management_policy` to med_power_with_dipm

Tried monitoring disk io using `iotop -ao` command but did not observe any significant amount of read or writes to/from HDD.

Also tried using [asusctl](https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl) to switch power profile but it doesn't seem to change any parameters related HDD.

Even after setting these values no change in HDD temperature.

Is there something that windows is doing differently than linux power management for HDD?
What can be done to achieve results similar to Windows 11?

Comment: Mapping? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen by mapping I mean if there are any common parameters between linux and windows which will allow to reduce HDD temperature. If no common parameters are available what can be done?

Comment: I used smartmontools and smartctl utility to check HDD temperature

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I have updated the question to avoid any confusion

Comment: `hdparm` values are interpreted by the disk's firmware and may differ from the man-page. Try other values. An example (although not for Seagate) is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1746076/8672).

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the direction! Let me try with multiple values. One more thing I read in almost every article is aggresive spin down can damage mechanical parts in HDD. Since you have done some experiments what is your observation?

Comment: I haven't done experiments, just searched for user cases.

Comment: Can you see what attributes the tools use to determine the temp (smartctl and smartmon)? Is it possible you add screenshot for both that include RAW values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows may be putting a secondary drive to sleep, while PopOS! does not. To see if that is the issue, run an app such as [KeepAliveHD](https://github.com/stsrki/keepalivehd) in Windows -- if the disk temp rises to that under PopOS!, you've found the cause of the difference.

That said, it's a choice whether you want the HDD running continuously, always available but running warmer, or you want to wait for it to spin up on each use, running cooler, *possibly* extending life. If used frequently, always-on might be the best setting. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1568374/can-the-os-put-an-external-hard-drive-to-sleep) for more information on letting a drive sleep.